# alpha value doesn't change in roll_out event flash cs5

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I am newbbie in Flash CS5 and AS3 and I have a problem! I have 3 rectangles on stage converted in MovieClips with given instance names. All three have the property of color effect: alpha = 50. I have type the following code in as3 layer :

```
addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, RollOverBtn);
addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, RollOutBtn);

function RollOverBtn(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    event.target.alpha = 100;
}

function RollOutBtn(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    event.target.alpha = 50;
}
```

The problem is that when the mouse rolls over one rect, alpha changes to 100. But when the mouse rolls out, nothing happens!

Any suggestions?

I have changed my code to :

```
btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, MouseOverBtn);
btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, MouseOutBtn);

btn2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, MouseOverBtn);
btn2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, MouseOutBtn);

btn3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, MouseOverBtn);
btn3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, MouseOutBtn);

function MouseOverBtn(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace("roll over"+event.target);
    event.target.alpha = 1;
}

function MouseOutBtn(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace("roll out"+event.target);
    if(event.target.alpha == 100){
        event.target.alpha = 0.5;
    }
}
```

and the trace message I get is :

```
roll over[object MovieClip]
roll out[object MovieClip]
```

This, as I can understand means that the roll_out is triggered but still not changing alpha property.

Answer (score 1):

1. Alpha can have a values in range 0-1, not 0-100.
2. Where did you attach listeners? They should be added to buttons.

Comment: You doesn't need that "if(event.target.alpha == 100)" conditional (and it's wrong, as alpha cannot be 100), try to delete it and see if now works.